# Remove Tint when Disabling Button

Tags: android, button

**EDIT:** The linked question specifies a method named `setColorFilter` to remove the tint. However, that method doesn't exist for `Button`s.

**Enabled Button**:
[image]

I have a button which triggers a Socket Connection. I want to disable it while I wait for the connection status. I have also added a `backgroundTint` to add a color to the Button without changing the default magic provided by the Base Button. (Which would get removed if I set `background` instead of `backgroundTint`)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/connectToServer"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="@string/connect"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/preset2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100000024" />
```

This is how I disable it:

```
connectToServer.setEnabled(false);
```

However, since the `backgroundTint` is set, the button gets disabled, but it still looks like it's there. (Of course, it cannot be clicked anymore, but it's bad UX.)

How can I solve this problem, without going the Make-Your-Own-Colored-Drawable for a button?

This is what I am trying to build. Only Colored.
[image: Credits: UX Planet]

Comment: did you try `button.setColorFilter(null)`

Comment: Button doesn't have a method named `setColorFilter`. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: yes you are right, try `setBackgroundTintList(null)` or `setSupportButtonTintList(null)`

Comment: `setBackgroundTintList(null)` sets the background a shown. See Update. (Also, `setSupportButtonTintList` doesn't exist for a Button. )

Comment: so `setBackgroundTintList(null)` solves your problem? or not

Comment: it does. had to change the text color too. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167886/discussion-between-akhilesh0707-and-abhishek-soni).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `setBackgroundTintList(null)` and value as `null`.

for example, this will solve your problem

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(null)
```

Or you can set color using

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(context.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.color_name));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative for this purpose you can use `alpha`.

For example:

if button enabled then use

```
button.setAlpha(1f);
```

and if button disabled then use

```
button.setAlpha(0.5f);
```